# show that mean curvature equal zero or $v_p$ $w_p$ are are principal vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $M$ be a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ , and $p$ be a point in $M$ i.e. $p\in M$ .
Suppose that $v_p$ and $w_p$ are two tangent vectors to $M$ ate the point $p$ , such that  $v_p.w_p=0$ and $S(v_p).S(w_p)=0$, where $S$ is the shape operator and it's defined by $S(v)=-\nabla_vU$ and $\nabla_vU$ is the covariant derivative of $U$ with respect to $v$ and $U$ is the unit normal vector field to the surface $M$. My question is show that the the mean curvature either $H=0$ or  $v_p$ and $w_p$ are principal vectors. Any hint I will appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you pick an orthonormal basis of principal directions, say $e_1,e_2$, and write a formula for $S(v)$ for $v=\cos\theta\, e_1+\sin\theta\, e_2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin but why $v=\cos\theta e_1+\sin\theta e_2$ we dont have that $v$ is a unit vector could you please clearify this .

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried to follow your steps and i get the following result $(k_1^2-k_2^2)\cos\theta\sin\theta=0$ so if $k_1=-k_2$ then $H=0$ if $k_1=k_2$ then p is umbilic point but i didn't know how to get red of this case when $k_1=k_2$

Comment: At an umbilic, every (nonzero) tangent vector is an eigenvector of the shape operator.